# rack-cache not found in any of the sources error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to creating a rails application. I'm going through this [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), and running into the issue when launching rails server. When I execute the commands (rails server or bundle exec rails server) I get the following error:

```
←[31mCould not find rack-cache-1.0.3 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, because rack-cache is installed. I've already run bundle install, but that doesn't fix anything.

This is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

my gem list is:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
actionpack (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
activemodel (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
activeresource (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
activesupport (3.1.0, 3.0.9, 3.0.0)
arel (2.2.1, 1.0.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
childprocess (0.2.2)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
commonwatir (2.0.2, 1.9.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
execjs (1.2.9)
ffi (1.0.9 x86-mingw32)
firewatir (1.9.4, 1.9.2)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (2.10.0)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
jquery-rails (1.0.14)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.16)
mocha (0.9.12)
multi_json (1.0.3)
nokogiri (1.5.0 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.3, 1.2.4)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
railties (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2)
rautomation (0.6.3)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rubigen (1.5.6)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
sass (3.1.7)
sass-rails (3.1.2)
selenium-webdriver (2.6.0)
sprockets (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.4 x86-mingw32)
taglob (1.1.2)
taza (0.8.7)
term-ansicolor (1.0.6)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
uglifier (1.0.3)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir (2.0.2, 1.9.2)
watir-webdriver (0.3.3)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.6.5)
win32console (1.3.0 x86-mingw32)
windows-api (0.4.0)
windows-pr (1.2.0)
xml-simple (1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not getting any of these:
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00:00:00.000000000Z"

If so, edit the gemspec file and change the dates to "2011-08-27" removing 00:00:00.000000000Z

This is the same for any of the gems, not just rack-cache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rack-cache 1.1 is being loaded but Rails is looking for 1.0.3. Since your `Gemfile.lock` list lost its indentation it's not clear which gem is requiring it but you might try putting `gem 'rack-cache', '1.0.3'` or `gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.0.3'` at the top of your `Gemfile` (after `gem 'rails'`).

Comment: it says that actionpack 3.1.0 requires rack-cache ~> 1.03. I tried putting the gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.0.3' in my gemfile after the gem 'rails', like so 'source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.0.3'' but i still get the error.

Comment: so apparently the invalid date in the gemspec errors i was getting, was also a cause. I fixed that error, by replacing the existing date with s.date = %q{2011-05-21} and the rails server started.